# What is the best practice for model filtering in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a use case where I want to be able to filter a collection in the index action of a controller

- 1) scoped by the current_user models AND if submitted
- 2) `params[:ids]`

I use to delegate the filtering to the model with scope or class methods:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weapons

  def self.filter_by_weapons(weapons)
    where(weapons: weapons)
  end
end
```

And in the controller

```
def index
  @zombies = Zombie.filter_by_weapons(current_user.weapons)
end
```

it works well. However if I want my application to be able to filter the `zombies`based on a list of ids, I will do:

```
def index
  @zombies = Zombie.filter_by_weapons(current_user.weapons)

  if params[:weapons_ids]
    @zombies = @zombies.filter_by_weapons(Weapon.where(id: params[:weapon_ids]))
  end
end
```

However this breaks the rule that only one model should be called in the controller action.

I tried to scope by ids instead of model instances but the problem is reverse and I have to map the ids of `current_user.weapons`

**So, what is the best way to do that ?**

Comment: I dont have time to post a full answer but check out lambda scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor your method to the following:

```
def self.filter_by_weapons(weapons)
  weapon_ids = weapons.first.kind_of?(Weapon) ? weapons.map(&:id) : weapons
  where(weapons: { id: weapon_ids.presence || -1 })
end
```

And use it like this:

```
def index
  @zombies = Zombie.filter_by_weapons(current_user.weapons)
  @zombies = @zombies.filter_by_weapons(params[:weapon_ids]) if params[:weapons_ids].present?
end
```